# Show a Dialog in Different screens of Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I need to show a **Promotional dialog** in some activities of android application based on api data. I got this data on Splash screen i.e. on which screens this dialog will show. How i can implement this?

Do i need to use **Broadcast receivers** for this or should i use **Shared preference** to save data and then later use this data to show dialog or should use **Global variable** in app.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You should make one common dialog and use throughout your application. You can use _SharedPreference_ for saving the data. If your data is huge then you can use database. Also within _Application(Singletone)_ class you can manage your data too.

Comment: I got an array of screens on which dialog will show . it may vary in size acc to no of screens also it contains any image or web url or text message that will show on screen. So is it better to manage on Application class?

Comment: Then you can use SP or db